# Adding Multiple Login Pages in Jasperserver

Tags: jasperserver

I want to add multiple login pages to single jasperserver.
i have customize the code and added login1.jsp and login2.jsp in moudles/login/ folder.
also i have added following code in \jasperserver-war\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jasperserver-servlet.xml

> bean id="urlHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
>
> ```
>     <property name="properties">
>         <props>
>            <prop key="/fileview/**">jsFileViewContr</prop>
>
>             <!-- anonymous pages -->
>             <prop key="/login1.html">jsCommContr</prop>
>             <prop key="/login.html">jsCommContr</prop>
>             <prop key="/logout.html">jsCommContr</prop>
> ```

and

```
  <!-- js mac method name resolver -->
    <bean id="paramResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.PropertiesMethodNameResolver">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/login1.html">entry</prop>
                <prop key="/home.html">homePage</prop>
                <prop key="/login.html">login</prop>
```

I have also added following code to JSCommonController.java in com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.control package.

> public ModelAndView login1(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse
>   res)
>               throws ServletException {
>           setupLoginPage(req);
>
> ```
>     return new ModelAndView("modules/login/login");
> }
> ```
>
> public ModelAndView login2(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse
>   res)
>               throws ServletException {
>           setupLoginPage(req);
>
> ```
>     return new ModelAndView("modules/login/login");
> }
> ```

i deployed server after rebuilting it.
but when i enter

> localhost:8080/jasperserver/login1.html

it takes me to

> localhost:8080/jasperserver/login.html

and after login on this page it takes me to

> localhost:8080/jasperserver/login1.html

but when i try to login on this page login event occures succesfully but it keeps me on same page.

Anybody know how to add multiple login pages in jasper server??
Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way for it :) and answer is as follows:

**Procedure to add new login page:**
Create a new login jsp page. Example entry.jsp
Keep it in jasperserver-war/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/modules/login/
Add entry of property of page in urlHandlerMapping bean section in jasper-servlet.xml in anonymous pages section as follows:

```
<bean id="urlHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
     <property name="properties">
         <props>
            <prop key="/fileview/**">jsFileViewContr</prop>
             <!-- anonymous pages -->
             <prop key="/entry.html">jsCommContr</prop>
             <prop key="/login.html">jsCommContr</prop>
             <prop key="/logout.html">jsCommContr</prop>
```

Also add following code in same file in paramResolver bean section.

```
<bean id="paramResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.PropertiesMethodNameResolver">
     <property name="mappings">
         <props>
            <prop key="/entry.html">entry</prop>
                <prop key="/home.html">homePage</prop>
                    <prop key="/login.html">login</prop>
```

---

```
<prop key="/entry.html">jsCommContr</prop>
```

This will call controller servlet which is mapped as

```
<bean id="jsCommContr" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.control.JSCommonController">
```

Add following code in com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.control.JSCommonController.java

> public ModelAndView entry(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse
>   res)
>             throws ServletException     {
>         setupLoginPage(req);
>
> ```
>   return new ModelAndView("modules/login/entry");
> }
> ```

This will load entry.jsp from folder modules/login/ folder for url

> localhost:8080/jasperserver/entry.html

We also have to add this page entry to the filterInvocationInterceptor bean in applicationContext-security-web.xml

Modify applicationContext-security.xml as follows:

```
<bean id="filterInvocationInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager">
        <ref bean="authenticationManager"/>
    </property>
    <property name="accessDecisionManager">
        <ref bean="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager"/>
    </property>
    <!-- <property name="runAsManager"><ref bean="runAsManager"/></property>  -->
    <property name="objectDefinitionSource">
        <value>
            CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
            PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT
            /entry.html=ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR
            /login.html=ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR
           /logout.html=ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR,IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
```

Build the war file again and redeploy it on server.
Now you can use

> localhost:8080/jasperserver/entry.html

as login page.
To change UI of login page customize entry.jsp and pageSpecific.css.

Locations of files:

entry.jsp :- /jasperserver/jasperserver-war/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/modules/login/entry.jsp

jasperserver-servlet.xml :- /jasperserver/jasperserver-war/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jasperserver-servlet.xml

JSCommonController.java :-
Physical path: /jasperserver/jasperserver-war-jar/src/main/java/com/jaspersoft/jasperserver/war/control/JSCommonController.java
Package Path: com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.control/ JSCommonController

applicationContext-security-web.xml :- /jasperserver/jasperserver-war/shared-config/applicationContext-security-web.xml